# Not able to access a JavaScript function inside an Angula2 component

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular app I am not able to access third party JavaScript functions inside my component even if I import the js file and declare the variables inside the component.

Below is my code

```
 import 'mxgraph-js/dist/mxgraph-js.js';

 declare var mx: any;
 declare var mxEvent: any;
 declare var mxGraph: any;
 declare var mxRubberband: any;


EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: mx is not defined
Module1Component@http://localhost:8080/f31627203470d3f88f30.3.chunk.js:694:10
Wrapper_Module1Component@/Module1Module/Module1Component/wrapper.ngfactory.js:5:18
anonymous/View_Module1Component_Host0.prototype.createInternal@/Module1Module/Module1Component/host.ngfactory.js:13:32
AppView</AppView.prototype.createHostView@http://localhost:8080/app.js:12320:21
DebugAppView</DebugAppView.prototype.createHostView@http://localhost:8080/app.js:12719:25
ComponentFactory</ComponentFactory.prototype.create@http://localhost:8080/app.js:7294:21
ViewContainerRef_</ViewContainerRef_.prototype.createComponent@http://localhost:8080/app.js:9591:50
RouterOutlet</RouterOutlet.prototype.activate@http://localhost:8080/app.js:57517:29
ActivateRoutes</ActivateRoutes.prototype.placeComponentIntoOutlet@http://localhost:8080/app.js:56827:12
ActivateRoutes</ActivateRoutes.prototype.activateRoutes@http://localhost:8080/app.js:5679
```

But when I load the same js file inside index.html everything works fine. I am facing this problem in so many scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have installed the `mxgraph-js` package, you have to import it like:

```
import * as mx from 'mxgraph-js';

// and use it like
console.log(mx)
console.log(mx.mxEvent);
```

If you have `noImplicitAny` set to true in you `tsconfig.json`, you will have to declare a definition for `mxgraph-js` since there don't seem to be any typings for `mxgraph-js`.

Something like this:

```
// mxgraph.d.ts

declare module "mxgraph-js" {
    var mx: any;
    export = mx;
}
```

Comment: Thanks@Saravana, It is working fine, But I have small doubt if I have multiple variables do I need define, import and export everyone?

Comment: That depends on how it is declared in your library.

Comment: I am trying to integrate mxgraph editor using mxgraph javascript library using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mxgraph

Comment: Hi@Saravana, Any Solution?